# Java- incompatible types String cannot be converted into a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Basically I have changed one of my `String` fields `ItemCodes` into an array so that I can store more than one value.

When trying to change my other methods to allow this, I am struggling. By the way I am a first year undergrad so please don't laugh! My code reads data from an external file by the way.

```
 itemCodes= newArrayList<LibraryUser>();
......

public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner11)
{ surname = scanner11.next();
.......
itemCodes=scanner.next()
```

- this is my problem as the data is being stored into an arrayList and now I am trying to read it through a scanner. Can anyone help please?

the `extractTokens()` method is being called from a different class from the method `readData()` which opens the file and reads the data.

Comment: Are you trying to read the rest of the lines from the file and put those into `ItemCodes`?

Comment: Please, put your code  `in this style` for an easier readibility.

Comment: I need to read the number of items (in a local variable) then i need a for loop that reads and passes it into an array list using the itemsCode.add() method. I am just unsure how!

Answer (score 0):

`itemCodes` is an an `ArrayList`, not a `String`, yet `scanner.next()` returns a `String`. If you are trying to populate your list with all the other lines/items from your file, then use a `while` loop to iterate over the `Scanner`. For example:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    itemCodes.add(scanner.next())
}
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) for more information about the `Scanner` class.

Comment: I need to read the number of items (in a local variable) then i need a for loop that reads and passes it into an array list using the itemsCode.add() method. I am just unsure how!

Comment: What type is the local variable? Just a `String`? (if it is, what separates the items in the `String`?)